# Leaflet ImageLayer setUrl error handling

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have been using setUrl to dynamically change/update the image loaded in a Leaflet pane using ImageOverlay.  Is there an error handling function associated with ImageOverlay?  Right now, if I attempt to setUrl(url) and url does not exist, Leaflet will simply show a blank map.  What I would like to do is if the url does not exist, an error message "image not found" would be displayed.  I found tileerror but it is used in conjunction with loading tiles.  Is there an equivalent function for ImageLayer?

Comment: Can you post what you did(CODE)?

Answer (score 0):

No, Leaflet does not have this functionality as of 1.0.3. You might want to have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/ImageOverlay.js#L154) and submitting a patch to fire a `error` event in case the image fails to load.